# How to fix retain cycle between CFXURLCache and _NSURLSessionLocal?

Tags: memory-leaks, nsurlsession, retain-cycle

Was just wondering if anyone's run into this as well, and if it's anything to worry about:

[image: Retain-cycle between CFXURLCache and _NSURLSessionLocal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the session has to have a reference to the cache.  The cache probably takes a delegate, and the session is that delegate.  The NSURL APIs have always used a strong delegate model, so such a cycle would make sense.

I wouldn't worry about it; the retain cycle should get broken when you invalidate the session.  (If it doesn't, then file a bug.)

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm wondering what's going on since this didn't seem to be an issue before Xcode 8 / iOS 10. Seems like there are other issues (e.g. properties of singleton classes being reported as memory leaks) with memory leak analyses.

Comment: I tried to resolve this issue by invalidating session but it didn't work.